# Would you rather get more or fewer emails from Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, notifications, email

Would you rather get more or fewer emails from Stackoverflow?

Comment: ITYM *fewer* emails

Answer (score 4):

I get just enough - those that I ask for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The current amount is not *just right*.

Comment: Is this intentionally confusing?

Comment: @jjnguy: Shog9 says that yes, he would indeed rather get more or less emails from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mmyers Ok, that makes a little sense I guess...

Comment: @jjinguy, and if you're looking for little sense, meta is the right place to be!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, so far the only emails I've gotten were ones offering me free stuff. I think I can handle that.

Oh, I also got one from a moderator letting me know he'd followed up on something I flagged. But I emailed him back and I think it scarred him enough that none of the others has tried it since.